# Angular orderBy filter causes drag/drop to drop wrong item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm building a drag and drop song list thing with Angular, angular.ui and various bits of code that I've cobbled together from various blogs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9Gq6GgRhxFGAy5xuMeCM?p=preview

1. Drag and drop a song from "songs" to set 1. It works as expected.
2. Use the dropdown to reorder the songs list by a different option, eg song title.
3. Now drag and drop a song from the "songs" to set 1. The wrong song is dropped. It seems to take what it thinks is the right song from the original ordering of the songs.

How can I make the drop code update to reference the newly ordered array when the orderBy filter is called?

It's as if I need to have a callback which rebinds the  `drop:function(event,ui)`  on line 79 of app.js, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Any pointers very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's fixed now and working great.
Here is an [example](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/filter).

i've also added an [example that shows a search filter](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/demo/dnd-search-filter.html) into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

They take the wrong element. https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/src/angular-dragdrop.js, line 61 -> dragModelValue does not take filters/repeats into account.

Answer (score 0):

ags is correct, they don't take into account repeats with filters. I've sent in a pull request to fix this, you could just grab my code. Here's my issue with the commit in it: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/issues/38